# Ionic3 system icons

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have set of custom system icons(png files) and they're in drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi and drawable-xxxhdpi folders for android.

Now my question is when I use them how should I call them?
For example, I want the system to pick the correct edit_pencil.png

This is what I have at the moment and I know this explicitly define the edit_pencil.png which I don't want. Could anybody help?

```
<img class="addPictureIcon" src="assets/img/drawable-xhdpi/edit_pencil.png" 
(click)="selectPicture()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using ionic framework, you have to place your images inside `src/` folder, probably `src/assets/images`.

Those platform folders are created automatically, so if you place anything there you are making a mistake.

To call an image it would be

```
<img src="src/assets/images/edit_pencil.png">
```

In your case, you are working with responsive images, so you should make some `@media` queries to call the right one, for example:

```
<img class="edit-pencil">
```

Css

```
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
  img.edit-pencil {
    content:url("xsmall-edit_pencil.png");
  }
}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
  img.edit-pencil {
    content:url("small-edit_pencil.png");
  }
}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
  img.edit-pencil {
    content:url("medium-edit_pencil.png");
  }
}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
  img.edit-pencil {
    content:url("large-edit_pencil.png");
  }
}
```